# Displaying image from spring boot REST server

Tags: html, file, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot REST server.

The controller is returning the stored image as :

```
@ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Resource> myController(@PathVariable("id") final Long id){
   ...
}
```

How do I display it in my html page ?

```
<html>
  ...
     <img src="???"/>
  ...
</html>
```

I can add a JQUERY / AJAX code that will retrieve the picture for me this way, but what do i do with it then ?

Comment: Not possible with a plain html page. 
You need somthing that consumes your Rest Endpoint like Javascript (e.g. jQuery) on client side or  a template engine like Thymeleaf on server side.
HTML alone can not do anything with your REST endpoint.

Comment: I will add JQuery/Ajax call to get the image that way. What then ?

Comment: look at this example: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-ajax-example/

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution in these links :

https://o7planning.org/en/11765/spring-boot-file-download-example
https://community.liferay.com/forums/-/message_boards/message/26404099

1) I read the image as a byte array

2) I must encode it to Base64

I use Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(my-image-bytes).getBytes()

3) I return it as ByteArrayResource :

```
return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "inline; filename=\"" + name + "\"")
                .contentLength(data.length)
                .body(new ByteArrayResource(data));
```

4) in my page, i load it as an image this way :

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'url-to-get-image-api-controller',
                type: 'GET',
                statusCode:{
                    200: function(data){
                        $("#thumb1").html('<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' + data + '" />');
                    }
                }
            });
```

This works.